# Optional parameter in the function of c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have to method in model of my asp.net mvc project.

```
public JsonResult GetProductsByDepList(string depID)
{
  JsonResult jr = new JsonResult();
  var _product = from a in DataContext.GetProductsByDep(Convert.ToInt32(depID))
  select new { ID = a.ID, ProName = a.Name };
  jr.Data = _product.ToList();
  jr.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
  return jr;
 }


 public JsonResult GetProductByCatList(string depID, string catID)
 {
   JsonResult jr = new JsonResult();
   var _product = from a in   
   DataContext.GetProductsByCat(Convert.ToInt32(depID),Convert.ToInt32(catID))
   select new { ID = a.ID, ProName = a.Name };
   jr.Data = _product.ToList();
   jr.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
   return jr;
 }
```

I want to combine these 2 method, it is work the same each other, except the parameter of the function.

Any ideas please.

Comment: Given that these two methods do different things, why do you want to combine them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [optional argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
public JsonResult GetProductByCatList(string depID, string catID = "0")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 public JsonResult GetProductByCatList(string depID, string catID = "-1")
 {
   //common shared code
   return jr;
 }
```

Assuming that default value is `-1` for `catID`

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
public JsonResult GetProductByCatList(string depID, string catID = null)
{
  JsonResult jr = new JsonResult();
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(catID))
  {
      var _product = from a in DataContext.GetProductsByDep(Convert.ToInt32(depID))  
      select new { ID = a.ID, ProName = a.Name };
      jr.Data = _product.ToList();      
  } else {
      var _product = from a in   
      DataContext.GetProductsByCat(Convert.ToInt32(depID),Convert.ToInt32(catID))
      select new { ID = a.ID, ProName = a.Name };
      jr.Data = _product.ToList();      
  }
  return jr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
   public JsonResult GetProductsByDepList(string depID)
   {
       return GetProductByCatList(depID, null);
   }

   public JsonResult GetProductByCatList(string depID, string catID)
   {
       JsonResult jr = new JsonResult();
       var _product = null;
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(catID))
       {
           _product = from a in   
               DataContext.GetProductsByCat(Convert.ToInt32(depID),Convert.ToInt32(catID))
               select new { ID = a.ID, ProName = a.Name };
       }
       else
       {
           _product = from a in DataContext.GetProductsByDep(Convert.ToInt32(depID))
               select new { ID = a.ID, ProName = a.Name };
       } 

       jr.Data = _product.ToList();
       jr.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
       return jr;
   }
```

Comment: this has errors, you can't declare `_product` twice and you can't just put the `select` bit off on it's own after the if/else statements.  Also you need a `return` in the top function.

Comment: But otherwise this has potential :)

Answer (score 1):

Default parameters are available from 4.0 version. Also, read this article from MS
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/85556.aspx